# changing master details to lookup field in salesforce

Tags: administration, relationships

I am preparing for advance admin of certification, one of the question is changing the master details relationship to lookup and deploying from sandbox to production. answer is to do by change set but i am thinking that it has to be done by creating unmanaged package.

please let me know if this can be done by change set.

I know it's easier to do it in production but this is question for preparation.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  If you have access to sandboxes, it's best if you try it yourself and gain the hands-on experience.

Answer (score 1):

Unmanaged Packages cannot update existing metadata, and cannot be upgraded later. Any attempt to install an Unmanaged Package that has components with the same name in an org will automatically fail. As such, it is impossible to change the data type of an existing field by creating an Unmanaged Package and installing it in any org.